# How to make a KeyListener draw an Image for a Java applet

Tags: java, image, applet, keylistener

I am trying to make a java applet game for class that allow the user to enter up and down to move the "player" image and shoot the "zombies" using the space bar. I have a "bullet" image and am trying to use a KeyListener so that when the user presses the space bar, the "bullet" image is displayed on the screen at the players current location and travels across the screen. However when space is pressed, I get a run time error and the bullet image isn't displayed. If anyone could let me know how to fix this I would greatly appreciate it!

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ZombieAttackMain extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener{

    private Image background, normalZombie, fastZombie, tankyZombie,player,bullet, bloodSplat, cow;

    private Graphics bufferGraphics;
    private Graphics g;
    private Image offScreen;

    private final int POSITION_1_Y = 100;
    private final int POSITION_2_Y = 255;
    private final int POSITION_3_Y = 400;
    private final int POSITION_4_Y = 550;

    private final int PLAYER_X_POSITION = 250;
    private int playerYPosition = POSITION_3_Y;

    private int zombieStartingXPosition = 1000; //change to 1100 later
    private final int NORMAL_ZOMBIE_DX = -2;    //not final
    private final int FAST_ZOMBIE_DX = -3;      //not final
    private final int TANKY_ZOMBIE_DX = -1;     //not final
    private int zombieYPosition; //depends on the zombieYPositionRandom

    private int bulletStartingXPosition = 405;
    private int bulletYPosition;    //depends on player position
    private final int BULLET_DX = 5;    //not final

    private int bloodSplatX, bloodSplatY; //depend on dead zombie position

    //Called when applet starts
    public void init(){
        setSize(1100, 700);
        normalZombie = getImage(getCodeBase(), "NormalZombie.png");
        tankyZombie = getImage(getCodeBase(), "TankyZombie.png");
        fastZombie = getImage(getCodeBase(), "FastZombie.png");
        player = getImage(getCodeBase(), "Player.png");
        bullet = getImage(getCodeBase(), "Bullet.png");
        bloodSplat = getImage(getCodeBase(), "BloodSplat.png");
        background = getImage(getCodeBase(), "Background.jpg");
        cow = getImage(getCodeBase(), "Cow.png");
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    //Called after init, sets up thread and starts it
    public void start() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true){
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);     //about 60 fps
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public void update(Graphics g){
        if(offScreen == null){
            offScreen = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            bufferGraphics = offScreen.getGraphics();
        }
        bufferGraphics.setColor(getBackground());
        bufferGraphics.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());

        bufferGraphics.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(bufferGraphics);

        g.drawImage(offScreen,0,0,this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(background,0,0,null);
        g.drawImage(cow,-15,115,null);
        g.drawImage(cow,-15,255,null);
        g.drawImage(cow,-15,400,null);
        g.drawImage(cow,-15,550,null);
        g.drawImage(normalZombie,zombieStartingXPosition,100,null);
        g.drawImage(tankyZombie,zombieStartingXPosition,400,null);
        g.drawImage(fastZombie,zombieStartingXPosition,255,null);
        g.drawImage(player,PLAYER_X_POSITION,playerYPosition, null);
        //g.drawImage(bullet,bulletStartingXPosition,336,this);
        g.drawImage(bloodSplat,bloodSplatX,bloodSplatY,null);
    }

    public void moveUp(Image player){
        if(playerYPosition == POSITION_2_Y){
            playerYPosition = POSITION_1_Y;
        }
        if(playerYPosition == POSITION_3_Y){
                playerYPosition = POSITION_2_Y;
        }
        if(playerYPosition == POSITION_4_Y){
            playerYPosition = POSITION_3_Y;
        }
    }

    public void moveDown(Image player){
        if(playerYPosition == POSITION_3_Y){
            playerYPosition = POSITION_4_Y;
        }
        if(playerYPosition == POSITION_2_Y){
            playerYPosition = POSITION_3_Y;
        }
        if(playerYPosition == POSITION_1_Y){
            playerYPosition = POSITION_2_Y;
        }

    }

    public void spawnBullet(){
        g.drawImage(bullet,bulletStartingXPosition, playerYPosition,null);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            moveUp(player);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            moveDown(player);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
            spawnBullet();
            break;
        } 
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }


    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void stop() {

    }

    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ZombieAttackMain.spawnBullet(ZombieAttackMain.java:118)
    at ZombieAttackMain.keyPressed(ZombieAttackMain.java:130)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Well obviously I'm very new to this, so if you could point it out to me that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: He meant that you should include the runtime error you're getting in the question. Edit the question and copy and paste the error from the console.

Comment: Ah I see. That is a no brainer, sorry :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you never initialize your `private Graphics g`. This might not seem obvious at first, because your `paint()` and `update()` methods use `g` just fine, but in those methods, `g` is a completely different, local `Graphics` object which is overshadowing your global `g`. My suggestion would be to remove the `private Graphics g;` because there's really no need to have another `Graphics` object floating around, and change `spawnBullet()` to:

```
public void spawnBullet(){
    bufferGraphics.drawImage(bullet, bulletStartingXPosition, playerYPosition, null);
}
```

However, because you clear the entire screen every update, this will not show the bullet... It would be even better to only draw in the `paint()` method, but that is a different topic altogether.

EDIT: showing an example of how to get the bullet to actually show

```
private int bulletStartingXPosition = 405;
private int bulletYPosition;    //depends on player position
private final int BULLET_DX = 5;    //not final

// NEW STUFF
private int bulletXPosition;
private boolean showingBullet = false;

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(background,0,0,null);
    g.drawImage(cow,-15,115,null);
    g.drawImage(cow,-15,255,null);
    g.drawImage(cow,-15,400,null);
    g.drawImage(cow,-15,550,null);
    g.drawImage(normalZombie,zombieStartingXPosition,100,null);
    g.drawImage(tankyZombie,zombieStartingXPosition,400,null);
    g.drawImage(fastZombie,zombieStartingXPosition,255,null);
    g.drawImage(player,PLAYER_X_POSITION,playerYPosition, null);
    //g.drawImage(bullet,bulletStartingXPosition,336,this);
    g.drawImage(bloodSplat,bloodSplatX,bloodSplatY,null);

    // NEW STUFF
    if (showingBullet) {
       g.drawImage(bullet,bulletXPosition, playerYPosition, null);
       bulletXPosition += BULLET_DX;
       if (bulletXPosition > 1100) { // if it went off the screen
           showingBullet = false;
       }
    }
}

public void spawnBullet() {

    // NEW STUFF
    if (showingBullet) {
        return; // don't want to reset the bullet if it's already on the screen
    }
    showingBullet = true;
    bulletXPosition = bulletStartingXPosition;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes sense to me now! Just saw the last part :P

Comment: Yea. That's because you clear the screen every update. You should draw the bullet only in the `paint()` method. There are a dozen ways to make it so `paint()` knows if it should draw the bullet or not, but the simplest for your case would be to have a global `private boolean showingBullet;` which you set to `true` in `spawnBullet()` and `false` whenever it hits something or goes off the screen, and inside `paint()` only draw the bullet `if (showingBullet)`. You would probably update its position right after drawing here, too.

Comment: You have been extremely helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: I edited the question to demonstrate in code what I meant in my last comment. You obviously don't have to do it that way, but it's just an example that I'm pretty sure should work.

Comment: I implemented the code you changed for me. Now that the bullet appears and moves across the screen, how can I make it so that when the player moves across the y axis, it remains on the y value when it was created? I've tried using a for loop with four if statements for each of the final y positions setting the bulletYPosition equal to the corresponding final y positions with a break after each if statement. Even with this it still moves across the y axis if the player does as well. You don't need to type out anymore code just the basic idea will do. You've helped a ton. Thanks!

Comment: That was my own fault for missing that in my example. In `spawnBullet()`, when you set `bulletXPosition = bulletStartingXPosition`, also set `bulletYPosition = playerYPosition`. Then in `paint()`, use `bulletYPosition` instead of `playerYPosition` when drawing the bullet.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the rest of your game :)